# Import excel sheet using jet.oledb.4.0 , setting first row as column name

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, jet

i am trying to import an excel file into a datatable in using **Jet.Oledb**. Here is my code:

```
            string sourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName) + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(sourceConstr);
            OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
            con.Open();
            oleDbCmd.Connection = con;
            DataTable dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

            string firstExcelSheetName=dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            string query = "select * from [" + firstExcelSheetName + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
            data.TableMappings.Add("Table", "dtExcel");
            data.Fill(dtExcel);
```

In the excel file, first row has the columnname. but my datatable is getting (f1,f2,f3,...) as column name and first row of the excel file as first row. So i can guess I have to tell that the first row contains columnName. But how can i make it happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a quote from [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel):

> "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

So you could try changing your connection string to set `HDR=Yes`.

Answer (score 1):

there is a only a little change as shown below, in the connection string i.e. sourceConstr in your case.

```
HDR=Yes
```

instead of

```
HDR=No
```

after change it would be

```
string sourceConstr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + fileName) + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
```

Comment: let me know how it goes, dealing with excel oledb has been quite bumpy  ;-)

Comment: it is going, where i want to send ;-)

Comment: :) cool - only after you reply - I see that @Daniel Kelley and me both answered this question almost the same time & similar too.

Comment: yah. he answered just 6 min before you. :)